# constant expression in c++ template argument

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11

I have a template, that takes a char argument like:

```
A<'T'>
```

I am storing my T in a variable like:

`const char ch = str[0];` //str is a string from my program

`constexpr char ch = str[0];` // this doesnt work either for me

I am trying to achieve this:

```
A<ch>();
```

I am using gcc 4.7 and have dabbled with constexpr but I havent been able to get that work

Any idea of a way to get this to work?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to specify the TYPE there via a string?  If so, that's not allowed.  If your question is different, then please clarify.  For example, there's a massive difference between `vector<int>` and `vector<"int">`.  The first is fine. The 2nd is not.

Comment: @Kevin : There's also a massive difference between `sometemplate<'a'>` and `sometemplate<"a">`. ;-] `vector<>` is a bad example because it only takes types, but non-type template parameters are legal for integral types.

Comment: @ildjarn - What I don't know about templates could fill a book (and probably does, I need a good book on that), but I knew that if they're trying to specify the type of a template by the contents of the string, that such a thing was "not right".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can only work if *everything* is a constant expression:

```
constexpr char str[] = "Hello World";
constexpr char ch = str[0];
A<ch> x;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the contents of `str` are defined at runtime, then there is no way to achieve that. The compiler requires your template value to be set during compilation.

That is why this is valid:

```
A<'a'>();
```

Since `'a'` is a constant value, known during compilation. But this:

```
void foo(const std::string &value) {
    A<value[0]> t;
}
```

Is not, since `value[0]`, despite being a constant value, is not known during compilation.